# Error report from Google Play: NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the report I got in developer console of Google Play Store. from I am unable to reproduce the issue as I am unsure where it's happening in my application. Found none when I searched for similar stacktraces.

Comment: Can you show the code?
I think some thread is posting that problem.

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar I am unsure where it's happening. My app has atleast 30 fragments. So unable to share code.

Comment: can you Show some code sample and full logcat values?

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas I am unable to reproduce the issue. So I am not sure which code to show you and my logcat has no stacktrace about this report.